# Regexp match smth like &lt;a href="..."&gt; javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I managed to match `<a href="http://localhost:3000/#/project/57fa46a56fd91a88201943dc">` with `<a href[^\>]*>`.

But from server comes secured information with omitted parenthesis, e.g. `&lt;a href="http://localhost:3000/#/project/57fa46a56fd91a88201943dc"&gt;`. I cannot just write `&lt;a href[^\&gt;]*&gt;` because it reacts on any charachter `&`, `g`, `t`, or `;` in `href` attribute.

I can find information about matching words of one character after another but for some reason it doesn't work in negation `[^\(&gt;)]`.

So, what is the way to manage it so the code look fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best fix is probably one that fixes your server so it returns your HTML a tag with correct `<` and `>` characters, rather than the encoded `&lt;` `&gt;`.

If that's not a possibility, try:

`<|(\&lt)a href...` which should match < *or* the literal &lt (& must be escaped, lt do not need to be escaped).

Check it works on [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com)

Comment: I refactored my code in other way and now the task is much easier. for <a ..> tag's parenthesis I used {} instead of <> and they aren't changed on server side. Anyway, thank you for your answer.